# Beginner: Python - iterating through rows of csv, append result

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to input data from a csv and run that through a simple function and return it to the same CSV but appended onto the end of the row.

I'm having a hard time understanding the difference between the various modes(r, r+, a+, etc).

I've read the documentation but as a beginner am not understanding quite what they mean and which one is the right for me to be using in this case.

```
def appendCurrentTime():
    with open("file.csv", "??") as myfile:  #Opens File
        reader = csv.reader(myfile)         
        for row in reader:                  #Runs through each row
            myfile.write(current_time(row[1])) #appends the time, pulling in row[1] into current_time
```

**Also posting code for the first time, sorry if it doesn't come through clearly.

Comment: Is this Python 2.x, or 3.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, the main problem is that the CSV file is not a "database", so you can't modify a row in the middle without corrupting the next row.

So, open the source file in "rb" mode and destination file in "wb" mode, and AFTER you processed the whole file - delete original and rename new file to the original name.

And, description for the cases you specified:

```
"r" - open text file for reading, starting from the beginning.
"r+" - open text file for reading and writing, starting from the beginning.
"a+" - create file if not exists; then open as a text file for reading and writing, starting from the end of file, plus you can only write to the end of the file.
```

In short, "R" means Read, "W" write, "+" - "and other way around", "B" - binary, absense of "B" means text. "A" differs from "W" in that "W" clears the file contents when you call `open`.

IMHO you should probably open files in binary mode most of the time, even if they are logically "text", to prevent unintended conversions of special characters (especially important with Unicode). So, I would recommend "wb" to "write new file", "rb" to "read existing" and "ab" to "append to existing file" e.g. a log file.

For even more information, read the documentation for the POSIX [fopen function](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fopen/) - Python tries to adhere to its semantics as much as possible, even on Windows systems.

Comment: so in this case would "ab" be best?

Comment: I read your code more carefully, unfortunately you need to restructure it. Please see the updated answer for details.

Comment: @user3195487: Let's say you've got a new CSV file that's created every day, and a `daily_summaries.csv` to which you add a summary of each day's CSV file. Then it would make sense to use `"ab"` mode for the summaries.

Comment: @abarnert Indeed, though I believe the main confusion is that needed "append to the end of (each) row" differs massively from the POSIX "append to the end of file" semantics.

Comment: @wizzard0: Yes, it's important to make it clear that "a" is for appending rows to the end of the file, not for appending columns to the end of each row. Maybe [an example](http://pastebin.com/ET66t6mR) will help. Your answer already explains that to append a new row to each file, you have to rewrite the whole file line by line (generally using "w" mode, on a temporary file).

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a CSV file and implied text, the "rU" flag would be appropriate.  The r flag means read and U is universal line terminator mode.  This way it won't matter if the file is using Windows, Mac or Unix line terminators.

Also take a look into the `Sniffer` provided by the CSV library. It will automatically detect most dialects for you and can be passed into the `reader` function.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Sniffer

Comment: You usually want to open it as `"rb"` rather than `"rU"`, and let the csv code handle newlines instead of the file code—especially if you're using the `Sniffer`. That's why all of the examples in the docs use `'rb'`

Comment: Usually, but the line terminator is hard coded in the reader (at least in 2.7) and I've had trouble with \r\n newlines without the Universal flag on. By default reader recognizes \r or \n.  So I was just suggesting it as an alternative.